# Why doesn't an instantiation of Function have all the properties stored in Function.prototype?

Tags: javascript

I understood that an instantiation of a constructor function has the constructor function's `.prototype` property stored in a `__proto__` property. This is the case with `Object`.

[image]

However with `Function`, the instantiation doesn't have all the properties stored in `Function.prototype`. Why is this?

[image]

Comment: In your `new Object` image, you're seeing the properties because you expanded the `__proto__` property. You didn't do that for `new Function`

Comment: They are listed in the `__proto__` property of your instance, just like you show with your object instance.

Comment: @slappy Thank-you!